# Is it possible to display the venn diagram within a universal set?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib-venn

Is it possible to display the universal set using matplotlib-venn? I'm new to both python and the matplotlib package, so I'm not actually sure what's possible and what's not.

I'm trying to create a venn diagram generator that accepts the values for each circle and then an argument (ex. A intersection B), then highlights only the intersection of the two circles. Basically, this is what I want the output to be.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python has package *matplotlib_venn* but it needs some tricks in your case.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib_venn import venn3
A = set([9,3,6])
B = set([2,4,6,8])
C = set([0,5,1,7])
v = venn3([A,B,C], ('P', 'Q', 'U'))

v.get_label_by_id('100').set_text('\n'.join(map(str,A-B)))
v.get_label_by_id('110').set_text('\n'.join(map(str,A&B)))
v.get_label_by_id('010').set_text('\n'.join(map(str,B-A)))
v.get_label_by_id('001').set_text('\n'.join(map(str,C)))
v.get_patch_by_id('001').set_color('white')
plt.axis('on')
plt.show()
```

[image: venn]

You can use *plt.annotate* for configuring the position of values

Comment: Is there any way to shade the box or axis itself? I'm trying to get the same result as with the link provided. [venn](https://www.onlinemathlearning.com/image-files/xvenn-diagrams.png.pagespeed.ic.lfu_eFuUlc.png)